# Win7 / IE11 sharer.php via popup — auto-resizing bugged?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-sharer

In IE11, on Win7, with a basic popup call to sharer.php (paste this in console):

```
window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=google.com', 'anything', 'width=300,height=300');
```

For me, the popup resizes to fit it's contents (it has done this for a while), but then continues to expand horizontally, until its 100% width of my screen. Even if I attempt to manually move the window around, it constantly snaps back to full width.

Answer (score 0):

this is, by the time of writing, an offical open bug report:
https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/596391143781665/